# Setting a Cover image responsive on high density displays

Tags: css

I have one serious problém. I did not found the solution yet, so i hope you know.

I am doing websites. I need to make responsive cover background image.(that covers whole page). I started with:

```
/* Location of the image */
  background-image: url(main.jpg);

  /* Background image is centered vertically and horizontally at all times */
  background-position: center center;

  /* Background image doesn't tile */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  /* Background image is fixed in the viewport so that it doesn't move when 
     the content's height is greater than the image's height */
  background-attachment: fixed;

  /* This is what makes the background image rescale based
     on the container's size */
  background-size: cover;

  /* Set a background color that will be displayed
     while the background image is loading */
  background-color: #464646;
```

This code just works, even if i resize the window and so.. So it is very well. But problém appears on height-resolution screens, like iPad or iPhone. There, the image is very very zoomed and kinda pixeled or unfocused. I thought, it is because low image resolution, but than i realised, that the image is nearly 5K. I want to make it responsive like on [this site](http://hydroboys.cz)

Any help be good, need to solve it quickly!

Thanks

Comment: what does this have to do with SEO? Also can you share a demo?

Comment: Could have something to do with retina, see this https://erikrunyon.com/2010/10/retina-display-and-css-background-images/

Comment: Yes, it has to do with retina..

Comment: And SEO, cause it mostly happen in sfary browser...

Comment: I don't think you understand what SEO is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a media query in CSS to manualy configure the background-image on retina displays (or other high-resolution screens).

See [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/).

**Mediaquery retina displays:**

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) { ... }
```

**And more furute proof:**

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) { ... }
```

---

Questions:

- [What are media queries?](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)
- [What is DPI?](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi3ypq93-fKAhUFmg4KHSwXBKkQFghBMAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDots_per_inch&usg=AFQjCNFXyOge__8RAmKGfbzzX7DC3PvRTA&sig2=ENLTWTCJOzOX71mI9lSX0w&bvm=bv.113370389,d.ZWU)
- [What is device pixel ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8785677/5847011)

---

Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16154494/retina-displays-high-res-background-images) for a same question/answer.

Comment: Not exactly what i want... I need to use same image on pc and on mobile :/

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using background-attachment:fixed - for whatever reason this when used with background-size: cover on iOS causes this behavior. So if you add the following it should be resolved:

```
/* for background-size:cover replacement on iOS devices */
@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) and (device-width: 320px), (device-width: 768px) {
    header {
      -webkit-background-size: auto 150%;
      background-attachment: scroll;
    }
}
@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) and (device-width: 320px), (device-width: 768px) {

    header {
      -webkit-background-size: 150% auto;
      background-attachment: scroll;
    }
}
```

Solution from [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12505205/1265817).